# Write a program that will create an integer array with 1000 entries

Tags: arrays

Write a program that will create an integer array with 1000 entries. After creating the array, initialize all of the values in the array to 0. Next, using the rand function, loop through the array and save a random number between 1 and 10 (inclusive) in each entry of the array.

This is for my homework due tomorrow but I need some help with it since I'm barely a beginner at code.

This is the only code I've made so far with single dimensional arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int mean(int array[], int size);
int main()
{

int i;

int array[5]={5, 1, 3, 2, 4};
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{
printf("%d", array[i]);
}
printf("\nThe mean is %d", mean(array,5));
return 0;
}

int mean(int array[], int size)
{
int i, sum = 0;
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    sum=sum + array[i];
}
return sum/5;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? Where are you stuck?

Comment: the whole thing, i really dont understand it, this array stuff is hard

Answer (score 0):

Not sure *why* you wrote a program to calculate the mean, given that there's *nothing* in the requirements about that.

However, you just have to think about the steps. Note that the following example do not perfectly match what you need, they're there just to show you the *method,* not to be cut and pasted into your assignment.

First, you can create an array of size (for example) seven with the statement:

```
int value[7];
```

You can then set all elements to a given value with:

```
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < sizeof(value) / sizeof(*value); idx++)
    value[idx] = 42;
```

(although, at the level of your assignment, it's probably better to use `7` rather than the `sizeof` expression).

In order to generate random numbers, you first include the requisite header and, as the first thing in `main()`, set the seed to something "random":

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
:
srand (time (0));
```

Then, at the time when you need to generate a random number from one to fifty inclusive, you can use:

```
int rnum = rand() % 50 + 1;
```

(keeping in mind the distribution won't be perfect but it should be more than good enough for the intended purpose here).

Whatever loop you chose above to initialise the array elements to 42 (or zero) can also be used to set them to random values.

That should be enough to get you started.